# Grunt.js - How to efficiently ignore (black list) node_modules folder?

Tags: gruntjs

I was wondering why my jshint grunt task is so dead slow. Thats short example config:

```js
var config = {
    jshint: {
        scripts: ['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**']
    },
    watch: {
        files: ['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'],
        tasks: ['jshint']
    }
}
```

What does that pattern? If I have understood things correctly, both file patterns are using grunt api to build file list for task. That pattern works, it filters everything inside node_modules away but it does it extremely slowly because before applying filter, grunt digs whole node_modules directory recursively (~100 MB).

Is there any way to actually tell grunt not to even look at node_modules?

That example config takes about 30s on my laptop. If using whitelist pattern istead of blacklisting, jshint task takes just couple of seconds. But whitelisting means I have to be looking Gruntfile all the time if I do any refactoring etc which is super annoying.

Current while list pattern looks like this:

```
var allJSFiles = [
    '*.js',
    '{browser,server,config,models,routes,tasks,schema,test,utils,views}/**/*.js',
     '!browser/bower_components/**'
];
```

Comment: Maybe try just `!node_modules` without `**/*` pattern?

Comment: `!node_modules` filters just folder itself but pass throught anything inside node_modules. And it seems `!node_modules/**/*` is same as `!node_modules/**` but I guess later is more _correct_ way to write that pattern so I changed it.

Comment: Whitelist is even more annoying if you want to run JSHint on multiple packages (each with their own node_modules folder) at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just add your JS files to a new folder off root? That way you can "ignore" `node_modules` by not including it in the list.

**Sample folder structure**

```
- root
- node_modules
  - jshint
- src
  // your bespoke code
```

**Grunt config**

```
var config = {
  jshint: {
    scripts: ['src/**/*.js']
  },
  watch: {
    files: ['src/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['jshint']
  }
}
```

Comment: I concur. The problem here is the structure of  your project. Drop all your JS into a separate folder and target it directly. I usually go as far as creating a js-source folder, running my jshint over that, then "uglifying" the JS into a separate minified folder. That way you're also avoiding running jshint over you minified scripts. The code in your question is also most likely jshint'ing your gruntfile.js, which arguable is unecessary

Answer (score 2):

Like Andy already mentioned, I'd recommend a different file structure as well, keeping your code in a "src" or "public" directory for example.

The problem here is that your rule

> '**/*.js'

always digs through all directories and only later excludes node_modules, which cannot be prevented at this point.

Not only because of this, but also to seperate code from other assets (images? documentation?), another structure should be the way to go.

Comment: The problem is I'm working on a big established project. That project is broken down into many packages in many different folders, so there are node_modules folders in many different places. How are you supposed to efficiently run jshint on something like that? On smaller projects I do put all my JS files in one folder, but that doesn't help me here.

Comment: well... how to put "ouch, you're screwed" in nice words?

As far as I understand, looking at the code, grunt delegates the file watching to Gaze (https://github.com/shama/gaze) and this receives the complete pattern... So as long as gaze does not validate the patterns during recursively digging into directories, there might not be much you can do...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you said that separating your node-modules from your JS is not an option in a comment to @Xosofox's answer, I would consider specifically targeting the folders you want to run jshint over rather than ignoring your node_modules folder.

```
jshint: {
    scripts: [
         'folderYoureInterestedIn/*.js',
         'anotherFolderYoureInterestedIn/*.js'
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` property like this:

```js
filter: function(filepath) {
   return (grunt.file.isFile(filepath) && filepath.indexOf('node_modules') < 0);
}
```